# Sequence of Number, through Iteration

Tags: r, sequence

I have the following vector of indices

```
V_ind = cumsum(c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
[1] 10 19 27 34 40 45 49 52 54 55
```

And I created the following FOR LOOP

```
k=1

for(ind in V_ind){
 if(ind<=10){
  print("ok")
 }else{
  print(c(V_ind[1:k]))
  k = k + 1
 }

}
```

Which gives as a result

```
[1] "ok"
[1] 10
[1] 10 19
[1] 10 19 27
[1] 10 19 27 34
[1] 10 19 27 34 40
[1] 10 19 27 34 40 45
[1] 10 19 27 34 40 45 49
[1] 10 19 27 34 40 45 49 52
[1] 10 19 27 34 40 45 49 52 54
```

However, what I try to acheive is the following result

```
[1] "ok"
[1] 10
[1]  9 10 19
[1]  8  9 10 18 19 27
[1]  7  8  9 10 17 18 19 26 27 34
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 16 17 18 19 25 26 27 33 34 40
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 15 16 17 18 19 24 25 26 27 32 33 34 39 40 45
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 14 15 16 17 18 19 23 24 25 26 27 31 32 33 34 38 39 40 44 45 49
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 27 30 31 32 33 34 37 38 39 40 43 44 45 48 49 52
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 29 30 31 32 33 34 36 37 38 39 40 42 43 44 45 47 48 49 51 52 54
```

This result goes as follows:

1. In the first iteration, we just print OK
2. In the second iteration, we extract the first element of the vector `V_ind`,
3. In the third iteration, we extract the first and second element of the vector `V_ind` together with the first element of the vector `V_ind` minus 1 that is the number `9`.
4. In the fourth iteration, we extract the first, second and third element of the vector `V_ind`, together with the first element minus 1, i.e. `9`, first element minus 2, i.e `8`, and second element minus 1,i.e.`18`.
5. In the fifth iteration, we extract the first, second, third and fourth element of the vector `V_ind` together with the first element minus 1, 2, 3 respectively, i.e `7,8,9`, also the second element minus 1 and 2, i.e `17,18`, and the third element minus 1, i.e `26`.

And this procedure goes until the end of the FOR LOOP. Is this even possible to be done in R, in a generic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i in seq_along(V_ind)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    print("ok")
  } else if (i == 2) {
    print(V_ind[1]) 
  } else {
    out_vector <- V_ind[seq(i - 1)]
    max_minus <- i - 2
    
    minus_indices <- rep(seq(max_minus), rev(seq(max_minus)) + 1)
    minus_vector <- c()
    for (j in rev(seq(max_minus))) {
      minus_vector <- c(minus_vector, rev(seq(0, j)))
    }
    
    out_vector <- numeric(length(minus_vector))
    for (k in seq_along(out_vector)) {
      out_vector[k] <- V_ind[minus_indices[k]] - minus_vector[k]
    }
    print(c(out_vector, V_ind[i - 1]))
  }
}

[1] "ok"
[1] 10
[1]  9 10 19
[1]  8  9 10 18 19 27
 [1]  7  8  9 10 17 18 19 26 27 34
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 16 17 18 19 25 26 27 33 34 40
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 15 16 17 18 19 24 25 26 27 32 33 34 39 40 45
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 14 15 16 17 18 19 23 24 25 26 27 31 32 33 34 38 39 40 44 45 49
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 27 30 31 32 33 34 37 38 39 40 43 44 45 48 49 52
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 29 30 31 32 33 34 36 37 38 39 40 42 43 44 45 47 48 49
[43] 51 52 54
```

You could define the indices at which to subtract, and how much to subtract, explicitly. (+1 added to seq for subtracting 0). Then you just have to append the last item (V_ind[i -1]) where no subtraction is performed to the vector

Answer (score 3):

One option using `purrr` could be:

```
map(.x = accumulate(V_ind, c),
    ~ map2(.x,
           rev(seq_along(.x) - 1),
           function(y, z) seq(y - z, y, 1)) %>%
        reduce(c))

[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1]  9 10 19

[[3]]
[1]  8  9 10 18 19 27

[[4]]
 [1]  7  8  9 10 17 18 19 26 27 34

[[5]]
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 16 17 18 19 25 26 27 33 34 40

[[6]]
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 15 16 17 18 19 24 25 26 27 32 33 34 39 40 45

[[7]]
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 14 15 16 17 18 19 23 24 25 26 27 31 32 33 34 38 39 40 44 45 49

[[8]]
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 27 30 31 32 33 34 37 38 39 40 43 44 45 48 49 52

[[9]]
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 29 30 31 32 33 34 36 37 38 39 40 42 43 44 45 47 48
[42] 49 51 52 54

[[10]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
[42] 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
```

And if it's important, you can simply add the "OK" iteration retrospesctively:

```
append("OK",
       map(.x = accumulate(V_ind, c),
           ~ map2(.x,
                  rev(seq_along(.x) - 1),
                  function(y, z) seq(y - z, y, 1)) %>%
               reduce(c)))
```

Likewise, if you need to leave out the last number from the original vector:

```
append("OK",
       map(.x = accumulate(head(V_ind, -1), c),
           ~ map2(.x,
                  rev(seq_along(.x) - 1),
                  function(y, z) seq(y - z, y, 1)) %>%
               reduce(c)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option where `sequence` plays the key role

```
lapply(seq_along(x), function(n){
  x[rep(1:n, n:1)] - rev(sequence(1:n) - 1)
})

# [[1]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  9 10 19
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  8  9 10 18 19 27
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  7  8  9 10 17 18 19 26 27 34
```

Where `x` is a subset of your vector:

```
x = cumsum(10:7)
```

If desired, just `c` "ok" to the above.